# What exactly happens with app when user presses home button?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, snapshot

What exactly happens with an app when the user presses the home button? Does iOS make a snapshot of current app's state?

If I'm right, how to "slip in" another snapshot? I need it for showing the main iOS screen after user presses home button twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iOS` takes screenshot before your application goes to background.

I got it from [Apple's official documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW47)

> **Remove sensitive information from views before moving to the background:** When an app transitions to the background, the system takes a snapshot of the app’s main window, which it then presents briefly when transitioning your app back to the foreground. Before returning from your applicationDidEnterBackground: method, you should hide or obscure passwords and other sensitive personal information that might be captured as part of the snapshot.

So, Here We can hide our *"sensitive personal information"* and the system takes a snapshot of the app’s main window and we are not able to change its feature.

**# sensitive personal information**

- Set a blurry screen overlay before the app goes in the background and once the app becomes active remove this overlay *(check **@cweinberger's** answer).*
- If it is `iOS 7` or later you can use the function [`ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch)
  Also, `allowScreenShot` flag can be explored in [Restrictions Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13).

For deeply read about it [Then this is the best documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW47)

Comment: To hide our "sensitive personal information" is exactly what i need...=)

Comment: @iPatel: thanks for sharing that; didn't know about the `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` method :)

Answer (score 4):

In order to achieve that, you could add a subview (i.e. ImageView with an image of your main screen) to your window in `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`.

When coming back (in `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`) you have to remove the subview.

However, Apple recommends to always show the latest state of the app (best user experience).

Example of AppDelegate implementation:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /* other code */

    self.overlayView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    self.overlayView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mainscreen_screenshot.png"];

    /* other code */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.window addSubview:self.overlayView];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.overlayView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Down-voting because of missing sample code isn't nice. The purpose of StackOverflow is not to receive free code but answers. Beside that, the code is pretty basic...